Reactable with footer works locally but not on Posit Connect
This app works locally, but not when deployed to the shiny server.
library(shiny)
library(digest)
library(reactable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    reactableOutput("rt")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$rt <- renderReactable({
    rmt <- reactable(mtcars[1:3,],
                     columns = list(
                       mpg = colDef(footer = 'A')
                     ))
    print(digest(rmt))
    print(sessionInfo())
    return(rmt)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

The problem is the footer.  Comment it out and it works on the Shiny sever.

The digest is the same locally and on the server. I think this proves that the exact same reactable is being generated on the server as locally.
I have other shiny apps deployed on this server that use the same footer and they work fine.
Running the server locally (inside rstudio IDE), but using an external browser works.
I don't see the table code generated when I right-click inspect element.
Deployment is on posit connect via 'Import from Git'
using renv

Local Console Output:
[1] "7f47b0250877eacd853d20e019725e8f"
R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22631)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices datasets  utils     methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] reactable_0.4.4 digest_0.6.36   shiny_1.8.1.1  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.12       rstudioapi_0.16.0 magrittr_2.0.3    xtable_1.8-4      R6_2.5.1          rlang_1.1.4       fastmap_1.2.0     tools_4.2.1       cli_3.6.3         jquerylib_0.1.4   withr_3.0.0       htmltools_0.5.8.1 yaml_2.3.10       lifecycle_1.0.4  
[15] later_1.3.2       sass_0.4.9        htmlwidgets_1.6.4 promises_1.3.0    rsconnect_1.3.1   memoise_2.0.1     cachem_1.1.0      mime_0.12         reactR_0.6.0      compiler_4.2.1    bslib_0.7.0       jsonlite_1.8.8    httpuv_1.6.15     renv_1.0.7

Shiny Server Log: (I removed timestamps)
[1] "7f47b0250877eacd853d20e019725e8f"
R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Red Hat Enterprise Linux
Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib64/libopenblasp-r0.3.3.so
locale:
[1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 LC_NUMERIC=C
[3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8 LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
[5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
[7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8 LC_NAME=C
[9] LC_ADDRESS=C LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C
attached base packages:
[1] stats graphics grDevices utils datasets methods base
other attached packages:
[1] reactable_0.4.4 digest_0.6.36 shiny_1.8.1.1
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Rcpp_1.0.12 withr_3.0.0 later_1.3.2 mime_0.12
[5] reactR_0.6.0 R6_2.5.1 jsonlite_1.8.8 lifecycle_1.0.4
[9] xtable_1.8-4 magrittr_2.0.3 cachem_1.1.0 rlang_1.1.4
[13] cli_3.6.3 promises_1.3.0 jquerylib_0.1.4 bslib_0.7.0
[17] tools_4.2.1 htmlwidgets_1.6.4 yaml_2.3.10 httpuv_1.6.15
[21] fastmap_1.2.0 compiler_4.2.1 memoise_2.0.1 htmltools_0.5.8.1
[25] sass_0.4.9



Try updating your libraries, including rsconnect, and see if that resolves the issue.

Thanks@IfeanyiIdiaye I updated everything, but the problem is still there.

This is a known bug in reactR 0.6.0 which impacts reactable
see:
https://github.com/react-R/reactR/issues/86
and
https://github.com/glin/reactable/issues/388
Fix this by using reactR 0.5.0 until they fix it.
> install.packages("remotes")
> remotes::install_version("reactR", version = "0.5.0", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")

